# error while connecting to the SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, database-connection

This is what I get:

> 'PatientDatabase.Properties.Settings' does not contain a definition for 'SQL' and no extension method 'SQL' accepting a first argument of type 'PatientDatabase.Properties.Settings' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
            conString = Properties.Settings.Default.patientDetailsConnectionString;

            objConnect.connection_string = conString;

            objConnect.sql = Properties.Settings.Default.SQL;

            ds = objConnect.GetConnection;

            MaxRows = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            NavigateRecords();

        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `SQL` exist in your .settings file in your project?

Comment: I am new to SQL, how to add SQL in .settings?

Comment: It's not in SQL, this is in your Visual Studio project.  Look up Settings files in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you don't have **SQL** in your settings file. Make sure that it exists and the casing is correct. Open the settings file and add node with SQL there. You can read the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of how you can do that.

Comment: Not me, your answer is correct :)  Upvoting to counter the neg rep.